# Storage on a dual Mac and Windows system

Tags: mac

If I have Windows 10 on my MacBook Air. I have 60 GB left on my Windows volume, and I have 100 GB on my Mac volume. Could I use an external hard drive to extend my Windows-accessible storage?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly mount an external hard drive when running Windows, but "extending" your Windows volume is only possible by re-partitioning your existing drive and reallocating space from the Mac portion.

Alternately, you could install a larger drive within your MacBook Air, partition to your liking then copy your data back.